Soil Types Sanity Check
I'm in the process of making a strategy game. I am using the FAO soil classification system for handling soils; the soil in a given tile has four characteristics:

production limit (how much food you can grow if you meet all the other requirements)
management requirement (how much active work is needed; this can be irrigation, drainage, difficulty working the soil, etc - it's a bit of an abstraction)
fertilizer requirement (how much fertilizer is needed in a particular soil; note here that I am not distinguishing between different kinds of fertilizer ie phosphorous vs nitrogen; fertilizer is a single product)
liming requirement (how much lime is required to manage acidity)

The exact values (0 to 100%) are not listed here, just a broad low/moderate/high/etc. I will fine tune the exact values later, but they'll always be estimates as I am by no means an expert on soil. What I'm looking for is a quick once-over to see if I've grossly mislabelled any of these. Where there is a question mark this means either the resources I was looking at (mainly the pdf collection on isric.org) didn't specify a given category (Solonetz/Solonchaks don't have acidity / amount of liming specified, for example; the chemical properties section just focused on the saltiness, so I had to guess) or because a category was too vague (Regosols are the "misc" category so I left them all on Moderate).
In cases where a soil varies widely in certain characteristics (i.e. Gypsisols can vary a lot in terms of how useful they are depending on how much gypsum they have) rather than trying to represent both ends of the spectrum I'm just going with an average.
Climate is handled separately, as is terrain. The focus here is strictly on agriculture, not livestock grazing (which will be governed mainly by terrain) or on forestry (also terrain). I will not be distinguishing between types of crops, or between say, staple grains vs orchards.
I don't need them to be perfect; at the end of the day, they're just for gameplay, not scientific simulation. But I would like to avoid putting in anything that turns out to be blatantly and jarringly wrong.



Soil Type
Production Limit
Management Req
Fertilizer Req
Lime Req




Acrisols
Low
High
High
High


Albeluvisols
Very Low
Fairly High
High
High


Alisols
Very Low
Fairly High
High
High


Andosols
High
Fairly Low
Moderate
Moderate


Anthrosols
Very High
Low
Low
Low


Arenosols
Low
Very High
High
Very Low


Calcisols
Fairly High
Very High
High
None


Cambisols
High
Fairly Low
Fairly Low
Fairly Low


Chernozems
Very High
Low
Low
Low


Cryosols
Low
Moderate
High
Moderate


Durisols
Very Low
Extremely High
High
Fairly High?


Ferralsols
Moderate
Fairly Low
Extremely High
Moderate


Fluvisols
Very High
High
Low
Low


Gleysols
High
High
Low
Moderate


Gypsisols
Low?
Very High
Fairly High
Moderate?


Histosols
Low
Very High
High
High


Kastanozems
High
Fairly Low
Low
Low


Leptosols
Very Low
Moderate?
Moderate?
Moderate?


Lixisols
Moderate
High
High
High


Luvisols
High
Fairly Low
Low
Low


Nitisols
Fairly High
Low
High
Moderate?


Phaeozems
High
Low
Low
Low


Planosols
Low
Low
High
High


Plinthosols
Low
Very High
High
Fairly High?


Podzols
Very Low
High
Very High
Very High


Regosols
Moderate?
Moderate?
Moderate?
Moderate?


Solonchaks
Fairly Low
High
Moderate
Moderate


Solonetz
Moderate
High
Moderate
Moderate


Umbrisols
Fairly High
Fairly High
Moderate
Moderate


Vertisols
Moderate?
Very High
Moderate
Fairly Low?




Interesting project.  I'd ask chatpgt to characterize the soil types you're interested in and see what it says. It probably has FAO etc docunents in its training corpus

If you can't tell whether the answer is correct or completely made up but plausible sounding to a non-expert, don't ask an LLM.

That aside, lime and fertilizer requirements sound like they are a function of the crop type being grown, no?

To an extent. Some crops do tolerate acidity better than others and would require less liming. However, in this case the particular crop isn't going to be factored in. There are temperature and precipitation requirements for certain crops, but in that regard I think I'm already pushing the edges of "too much detail." So I'm reducing it to just an overall liming requirement, for now.

your biggest problem is those classification are not  for agriculture. Thing with the exact same classification can have drasticlly diffrent agricultural potential. vertiol in a one location may be completely useless while in another it may be one of the best. you can easly simplfy this to the 12 major classifications or you may want to look at the US Land Capabilty Classification which is geared towards agricultural usage instead of structure. https://efotg.sc.egov.usda.gov/references/Delete/2015-11-14/123_land_capability_10232014.pdf

The US Land Capabilty Classification also breaks each type down so you could group most of those into them and drastically simplfy your problem. since the deciding factor on how useful most of the middling soils are is often tied to rainfall.  https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-A-PURL-gpo20777/pdf/GOVPUB-A-PURL-gpo20777.pdf this classification actually describes everythign you want.

The problem in that regard is the FAO classification system includes a lot of data about where in particular a given soil is likely to occur, both in terms of general description and in having real-world examples. The US LCC is a classification system for agricultural potential but doesn't really have any indication of where a given soil tends to occur (because it's just concerned with agricultural potential) and there's likewise a paucity of real-world example maps to draw on. So US LCC is actually a lot less useful than the FAO system.

Soil properties, especially productivity but also chemistry and even physical structure are completely climate and topography dependent, the same volcanic ash that creates the insanely productive allophanic soils of NZ's central plateau where the ground is well drained also creates a dense permanently waterlogged mess of swelling clay where the ash weathers in damp conditions. Light loess derived loams turn to glay podsols under tree cover. You simply can't look at soil in isolation from climate and vegetation cover.

Are you trying to make The Campaign for North Africa but for agriculture? Game design isn't the forte of Worldbuilding.

Ash: the resources I found on ISRIC paired with FAO maps of Earth as an example seemed to be a decent way to determine where soils ought to occur in a fictional world, but I would certainly be open to suggestions for a different approach.
Trish: I'm making a grand strategy game similar to Victoria 2, but in this case I'm just looking for a sanity check on the agricultural potential and limitations on different soils under the FAO classification system, which seemed like something that would be up Worldbuilding's alley.
